# Damaged 3 IP Cameras with replacement power supply

Tags: pcb

I have damaged 3 Edimax PTZ cameras because of a replacement power supply.  I am trying to figure out why the replacement power supply with DC output of 12V 2A would kill my cameras which operated from 12V 1A DC.

I have measured the actual output voltage from the original and replacement at 13.56 VDC and 12.04 VDC respectivly.  I,ve never encountered a situation where such a small difference in power supply specs could cause this type of damage.  Both supplys are rated at 12V. The original at 1A and the replacement at 2A.

I'd like to eventually repair my cameras and hope understanding possible causes of the damage may lead me to the damaged circuit board component(s).  I've already replace 3 Schottky Diodes on the board but no joy.  I don't see any physical evidence of burn out on the boards.

Sorry to go so long on my question but I'm totally mystified by this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

1. Are you sure the polarity of the output plug is the same?
2. Can you look at the output voltage ripple of both supplies on an oscilloscope?
3. It could be that there are load transients that the replacement supply doesn't deal with well causing overshoot.
4. Perhaps under load the replacement supply (even though it's rated at 2A) droops to the point where the input current rises enough to cause damage to something in the camera.

Most of those seem unlikely, and normally you would be fine making the substitution you did, but given that the damage did happen those are the possibilities that come to mind.